# отфильтровать почтовый индекс через регулярные выражения

Tags: регулярные-выражения, pandas

Есть датафрейм с колонокой Post_Index. Задача отфильтровать все компании из города Санкт-Петербург. Т.к. почтвый индекс данного города содержит 190000, я хочу получить все индексы начинающиеся с 19.... Но ничего не выходит :(

```
df_st = df_active[df_active['Post_Index'].str.contains(r'^[19]') == True]
```

Comment: Должно быть `r'^19'`. `r'^[19]'` вернёт строки, начинающиеся либо с `1`, либо `9`. А почему не `str.startswith('19')`? `== True` кажется лишним.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew спасибо Вам большое!!!

Comment: Как уже сказал @WiktorStribiżew,  `df_active[df_active['Post_Index'].str.startswith('19')]` - более идиоматичный вариант

Comment: `'^19[0-9]{4}$'` — вариант до кучи...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Используйте

```
r'^19'
```

Регулярное выражение `r'^[19]'` вернёт строки, начинающиеся либо с `1`, либо `9`.

В данном конкретном случае также можно использовать `str.startswith('19')`:

```
df_active[df_active['Post_Index'].str.startswith('19')]
```